# Azure AD B2C Reset Password Email Link

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to change the way the password is reset by the user on Azure AD B2C.
Today, the user receives a code by email, and he has to paste it.

My client wants the user to receive an email with a link to type a new password.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the policy to achieve their scenario.

You need to use "magic links" as described here:

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite

Please let me know if you still need any help.